# python and Tkinter. constructing a list of list with Entry.get

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The below script asks the user an input and open a window in consequence. Then I want to get the informations from the window and put them in a list of list or something like that in order to create an object of the class "Parameter". Everything works except when I try to extract the data with Entry.get to put them in a list of list.

```
class Parameter (object):
    def __init__(self,number_individuals_classes,payoff):
        self.nb_classes = number_individuals_classes
        self.payoff = payoff
    def __repr__(self):
        print('nc.classes: {} | payoff: {}'.format(self.nb_classes,self.payoff))


def get_parameters ():
    def get_payoff():
        global payoff
        payoff = []
        for i in xrange(len(entr)):
            payoff.append(map(Entry.get, entr[i]))
        fen1.destroy()


    number_individual_classes = input('Number of individual classes: ')
    fen1 = Tk()
    fen1.title('Enter payoff matrices')
    header1 = Label(fen1,text='Cooperation').grid(row=0,column=2)
    header2 = Label(fen1,text='Defection').grid(row=0,column=3)
    other_txts = []
    focal_txts = []
    vert_cop_def_txts = []
    entr = []
    iteration = 0
    for focal in range(1,number_individual_classes):
        for other in range(focal+1,number_individual_classes+1):
            focal_txts.append(Label(fen1,text='Effect on: {}'.format(focal)).grid(column=0,row=3*iteration+2))

            vert_cop_def_txts.append((Label(fen1,text='Cooperation').grid(column=1,row=3*iteration+2),Label(fen1,text='Defection').grid(column=1,row=3*iteration+3)))

            other_txts.append(Label(fen1,text=' '*65 +'Co-player: {}'.format(other)).grid(row=3*iteration+1,column=2))

            entr.append((Entry(fen1).grid(row=iteration*3+2,column=2),Entry(fen1).grid(row=iteration*3+2,column=3),Entry(fen1).grid(row=iteration*3+3,column=2),Entry(fen1).grid(row=iteration*3+3,column=3)))

            iteration+=1


    Button(fen1,text='Done',command=get_payoff).grid()
    fen1.mainloop()
    to_return = Parameter(number_individual_classes,payoff)
    return to_return

a=get_parameters()
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Update:

This work. what is the difference ?

```
from Tkinter import *

def super_function():
    out = map(Entry.get, entr)
    fen1.destroy()
    print out

fen1 = Tk()
entr = []
for i in xrange(10):
    entr.append(Entry(fen1))
    entr[i].grid(row=i+1)

Button(fen1, text = 'store everything in a list', command = super_function).grid()

fen1.mainloop()
```

P.s As I am a beginer, any other advice on my script is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you intend to do with this, it seems like you want to establish some kind of interaction matrix between each "individual class" but I may be wrong.

First, your function doesn't have any argument ( get_payoff() ), since you want it to extract something from entr, I would assume that you would want to put entr as an argument of your function!
Something like :

```
Button(fen1,text='Done', command=lambda : get_payoff(entr)).grid()
```

"lambda" will allow the function to be used without being called when the button is initially created in the GUI.

Second, when I execute (with the modification), I've got an error because in the function you will try to do the get() with None types variables. Your variable "entr" where you want to extract the data contains only None types, not textvariables from Entry widget. The reason is that you can't store widgets in an array like this. Each time you want to create an entry, you must create a variable (a textvariable) which will be the link to the entry:

```
# a is a string variable
a = StrVar()
# which is linked to the Entry "test"
test = Entry(window, textvariable = a)
# get the variable in Entry "test"
b = test.get()
# print on screen the result
print b
```

I don't know if that can help you or if I am completely off the mark here.

Comment: You're not at all off the mark, thks bserra. I didn't lambda. It will be usefull thks for it. Indeed entr contains only "None". I don't really understan why. As my number of Entry vary depending on the number_individuals_classes I'm obliged to use a list, isn't it ? How could I store all the information the user will enter in the entries in a list of list whatever is the number_individuals_classes ?

Comment: @Remi.b Entry() is the function for creating an Entry widget on a tk window. So by using it in your program, you successfully CREATE the Entry, but there is no textvariable linked to it. And with no link there is no way (at least for me) to extract the textvariable -string that you type in the Entry-.

If you want to see it simply, the Entry widget (like a lot of widgets) can be see like this:
    Entry(where you put it, what is it linked to)

And clearly in your code there is no link part. You just mention where it will be (fen1) and pack it (grid(row=xx, col = xx))

Comment: Oh Ok I get what you're saying. but then, may I ask why the script I had before worked (I added it to the post) ? in the Entry() function there's no such link (textvariable)

Comment: in your first version you defined entr as :
    entr.append((Entry(fen1).grid(row=xx, col =xx))
and in the second : 
    entr.append((Entry(fen1))

The difference is that in the first one you create the widget, so the result of the grid() method is None. The second one you store the widget itself into a table and then you create it (and hence you can get() the value without the textvariable defined)

Comment: Ok, evrything is clear to me now ! Thanks a lot for your help and all your explainations.

Answer (score 1):

The first and most important problem is that you are appending to the lists the result of the calls to `grid` (which is always `None`), instead of the widget:

```
focal_txts.append(Label(fen1,...).grid(...))
# ...
```

This should be:

```
focal_label = Label(fen1,...)
focal_label.grid(...)
focal_txts.append(focal_label)
```

Besides, you are trying to use `payoff` as a global variable, but there is no global name `payoff` before you use it in your callback function. So when you try to use it as an argument for the constructor of `Parameter`, it is not within the same scope.

In general, the creation of the widgets dinamically can be improved and the organization of your code would be much better if you use classes.